# explode and foreach problems

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, explode

A user enters URLs in a box like this:

1. google.net
2. google.com

I then try to validate / check the URLs, so:

```
function check_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    return $data;
}
```

After validation:

```
$flr_array = explode("\n", $flr_post);
```

So, I can validate each URL. But `mysql_real_escape_string` finds spaces between URLs and adds:

```
<--print_r information-->
google.net\r\ngoogle.com
```

My URLs should and look like these:

1. google.net
2. google.com

How do I remove `\r`, because it breaks everything else?
Is there a better way to validate URLs?

Tried with `str_replace`, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats where difference between single and double quotes comes into picture:

```
$flr_array = explode('\r\n', $flr_post);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to validate URLs is to use PHP's [`filter_var()`<sup>*docs*</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function like so:

```
if( ! filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))) {
  echo 'BAD URL';
} else {
  echo 'GOOD_URL';
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'd never heard of that function. Touché sir!

Comment: PHP's filter functions will change your life!

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_split instead,

```
$parts = preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', $data);
```

That'll split anywhere there's one or more \n or \r.

What are you doing the mysql_real_escape_string for? Is this intended for a database later on? Don't do an escaping BEFORE you do other processing. That processing can break the escaping m_r_e_s() does and still leave you vulnerable to sql injection.

m_r_e_s() MUST be the LAST thing you do to a string before it's used in an sql query string.

Comment: And use PDO prepared statements to further avoid sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions to validate URL's in your $flr_array.

With [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), if there is a match it it will fill the $matches variable with results (if you provided it in your function call). This is what php.net has to say about it:

"If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on."

Answer (score 0):

You can use : nl2br() — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

Example :

```
<?php
    echo nl2br("Welcome\r\nThis is my HTML document");
?>
```

Output :

```
Welcome<br />
This is my HTML document
```

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php